# Does TestNG affect the already existing project which have not used TestNG

Tags: eclipse, selenium, testng

I have a project (having packages and different classes)in eclipse(Juno Version) but is not written using TestNG. Now I am trying to install TestNG and Maven in eclipse.Will it affect my existing project??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Answer is `NO`.

`TestNG` libraries are added at Project level through eclipse.

Similarly, `Maven` in eclipse structures the Project you select while creating the Maven Project.

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Answer (score 1):

No, that won't affect your current project. Here you are just adding some plug-ins/extensions into your **IDE**. Any of the plug-ins/extensions should not affect your project.